# Nodejs server communicate with two network interface cards

Tags: node.js

Is it possible with a nodejs server to have it receive a message on one network interface and then output an HTTP request on a different network interface?

The scenario:
I have a device on a local network and I want the server to be able to receive data from that and format it into a request to update a third party web app.
I have confirmed that I am receiving the local message correctly, and I have confirmed that the format of the HTTP request should work using fiddler, but somewhere between the two parts I am having an issue.
I get a "socket hang up" error at the moment.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
Below is my server code. I have specified IP addresses for the incoming and outgoing messages, but I still get a socket hang up error. Can anyone spot anything else which could be causing this issue? 
I am wondering if I need to do something differently for a secure connection? (it is a https URL)

```
var url = require("url");
var http = require('http');


http.createServer(function (request,response) {
    var theUrl = url.parse(request.url);
    console.log(theUrl);
    var timeline = {   // Data to be sent to external web service
        channel: "#test",
        username: "Slash",
        icon_emoji: ":smirk_cat:",
        text: "Timeline Started: " + theUrl.path
    };
    var data = JSON.stringify(timeline)

    var options = {
        host: "example.com",
        path: "/path/to/web/service",
        localAddress: '172.20.1.53', // IP address of outgoing NIC
        method: 'POST',
        port: "443",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data),
        }
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res){
        res.on('data', function(resp) {
            console.log(resp)
        });
    });
    req.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
    });
    req.write(data);
    console.log(req);
    req.end();
}).listen(801, '172.30.2.92'); // IP address of incoming NIC
```

Comment: Outgoing interface is chosen by IP network layer routing rules of the operating system. However it sounds like your problem is not related to routing but something else in web server or configuration. (can you use curl to debug the request in the server machine?)

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to fix this issue, I just needed to change var req = http.request to var req = https.request

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify the interface by the assigned IP address.

For servers you specify it in `listen()` like so:

```
server.listen(8000, '192.168.100.14');
```

For outgoing HTTP requests you can specify it as `localAddress` like so:

```
http.request({
  localAddress: '192.168.5.27',
  // ...
}, ...);
```

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't seem to have helped. I have added the code to the question.